# ionic 4 virtual scroll - scroll to a specific element

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4, virtualscroll

i have a list of questions which should be rendered programmatically and unfortunately with **dynamic height**. in purpose of performance and get rid of lags i'm using **ionic virtual scroll**. the problem is that i have to implement **jumping** feature but since the target element is not rendered yet it can't find that element and so it can't scroll to that! i also tested **ngx-virtual-scroller** it's scroll to target works perfectly but it does not support dynamic heights and don't work perfectly if i don't specify item height. does any body has any idea about this problem!? that's killing me ;D

> consider that i'm on question number 3 and i have to scroll to
>   question 80!

[image: jumper button]
[image: target question]
thank you

Comment: why are you not using ionic component. Ref https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/virtual-scroll

Comment: @KhurshidAnsari thanks for your comment, but the main problem is ionic virtual scroll :-|